# Runtime Error 1004 while trying to add a range to a script in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The script below works fine for a single cell, but when I am trying to add the Range `Q3:Q200`, it throws the `Runtime Error 1004`.

VBA script:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As _
            Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    With Sheets("  Sheet3  ").Range("  Q3  ")
        If .Value = "  Shirts  " Then
            If Range("  R3  ") = "" Then
                MsgBox "  Save has been cancelled. You must fill Type of Shirts  "
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So this is the script that works?  Can you post what doesn't work?

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As _
Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
With Sheets("Sheet3").Range("Q3:Q200")
If .Value = "Shirts" Then
If Range("R3:R200") = "" Then
MsgBox "Save has been cancelled. You must fill Type of Shirts"
Cancel = True
End If
End If
End With
End Sub

Comment: @user3416778, edit please your question with this code - it's unreadeble in comments

Comment: I have Created a Drop Down from Q3 to Q200 where everytime I Should Select a Shirt it should prompt me to enter or select option in Row (R)

Comment: It works fine in case of selecting One Range only but incase of selecting Multiple Range, it returns with an error.....

Comment: You can't compare the `.Value` of a multi-cell range to a string. What are you trying to do? Look for the existence of *any* cell in the range with a value of "Shirts"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the range to find values of "Shirts".  Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("Sheet3!Q3:Q200")
    Debug.Print c.Address & "  " & c.Value
        If c.Value = "Shirts" Then
            If c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
                MsgBox "Save has been cancelled. You must fill Type of Shirts"
                Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could use `Range("Sheets3!Q3:Q200").Find("Shirts")` but I think that will actually require more code.